# Change font color and URL Dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am working on website *(HTML+PHP)*.Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salunkheganesh07/k5ao7u85/2/) of what I have done so far(sharing one for example).

Each image should point to different URLs.
There are few images whose color matches the font color.I want to change font size/color as image changes. Also URL should also change automatically as image changes.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
    <figure class="effect-lexi effect-chocolate">
        <div id="cf3" class="shadow">
            <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/22.jpg" alt="Image" class="bottom" />
            <img src="http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/21.jpg" alt="Image" class="top" />
        </div>
        <figcaption>
                <h2>Dark <span>Chocolate Smoothie</span></h2>

            <p>Description</p>  <a href="#">View more</a>

        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Is it possible ? Can anyone help me with it.?

Thanks,

Comment: Hey, what kind of information do you have in de backend? Do you know when the image will be conflicting of color? And the URL changing, you mean the link in the "View more" button?

Comment: I am not fetching any information from backend for this. Yes. I want to change link in "View more" button as image changes.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS3, you might be able to wield the blend mode to accomplish this.

https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/

Also, you would need to use the JavaScript History to change the URL.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest solution is to set the font color as an rgba. For example 
    color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);

As long as the images aren't black, this will adapt nicely to the color of the background. If you don't have any info from the back end, something along these lines is will probably be the way to go.